# BIND Setup - Serve internal LAN, query outside results

Tags: linux, dns

Setting up a internal private server for some testing on our corp LAN. I want it to be authoratative for a internal domain and hosts, but be able to resolve stuff on the internet (google, yahoo etc.)

I can get the internal part working just fine, but when i try to resolve something public, it fails. I am probably missing one simple flag in my /etc/named.conf (BTW, RHEL 7.3 is my OS).

I can paste the contents of my configuration, but thought I would start here.

I started very simple, just to get it working and then plan to add more as i go along. I just need to fix the external resolving issue i am currently having.

Thanks!

IllusionMan

EDIT: Nervermind. Think I figured it out. I had to setup 'forwarders' in the options section and turn on recursion. Right now, it is working the way i want.

Comment: It is a bad idea to have the same server being both authoritative and recursive. You should split these 2 functions into 2 separate servers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the contents of my `/etc/bind` on Debian with a config working the way you say you want - authoritative for a fake domain/tld (called fake.tld) on the local LAN using non-routable addresses (10.99.99.0/24 in my case) with reverse DNS for LAN addresses, and other lookups for "real" DNS sent out to the world (in this case, forwarded to google's 8.8.8.8).  The only files not represented here are the `/etc/bind/rndc.key` and `/etc/bind/bind.keys`.  File names are in bold, end of file indicator commented in the appropriate style for that file (ie, ; in a zone file)

**named.conf:**

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the 
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize 
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

//end named.conf
```

**named.conf.default-zones:**

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};


//end named.conf.default-zones
```

**named.conf.local:**

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "fake.tld" {
  type master;
  notify no;
  file "/etc/bind/db.fake.tld";
};

zone "99.99.10.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  notify no;
  file "/etc/bind/db.10.99.99";
};

//end named.conf.local
```

**named.conf.options:**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

     forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
     };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

//end named.conf.options
```

**db.0:**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  localhost.
;end db.0
```

**db.10.99.99:**

```
$TTL 3D       ; default ttl for records without a specified lifetime
$ORIGIN 99.99.10.in-addr.arpa.
@                      IN   SOA ns.fake.tld. root.fake.tld. (
                                2017012811   ;  serial number
                                1638        ;  ns refresh
                                204         ;  ns retry
                                10485      ;  authority expiry
                                256        );  min (RFC2308 §4)
; we dont use a hostname when we tell about our nameserver(s)
    IN  NS  ns.fake.tld.
; hostname in this case is the last quad of the IP address
1       IN  PTR gw.fake.tld.
2       IN  PTR ns.fake.tld.
3   IN  PTR dhcp.fake.tld.
10  IN  PTR fileserver.fake.tld.


;end db.10.99.99
```

**db.127:**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  localhost.
1.0.0   IN  PTR localhost.
;end db.127
```

**db.255:**

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for broadcast zone
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  localhost.
;end db.255
```

**db.empty:**

```
; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
;
; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
;
$TTL    86400
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  1     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
              86400 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  localhost.
;end db.empty
```

**db.fake.tld:**

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.fake.tld. root.fake.tld. (
                 2017062019         ; Serial
             ;   YYYYMMDDVV   
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@           IN      NS      ns.fake.tld.
@       IN  A   10.99.99.2
gw      IN  A   10.99.99.1
ns          IN      A       10.99.99.2
dhcp        IN  A   10.99.99.3
fileserver  IN      A       10.99.99.10
gitlab      IN  A   10.99.99.7
;end db.fake.tld
```

**db.local:**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  localhost.
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
;end db.local
```

**db.root:**

```
;       This file holds the information on root name servers needed to
;       initialize cache of Internet domain name servers
;       (e.g. reference this file in the "cache  .  <file>"
;       configuration file of BIND domain name servers).
;
;       This file is made available by InterNIC 
;       under anonymous FTP as
;           file                /domain/named.cache
;           on server           FTP.INTERNIC.NET
;       -OR-                    RS.INTERNIC.NET
;
;       last update:    Jan 3, 2013
;       related version of root zone:   2013010300
;
; formerly NS.INTERNIC.NET
;
.                        3600000  IN  NS    A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     198.41.0.4
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:503:BA3E::2:30
;
; FORMERLY NS1.ISI.EDU
;
.                        3600000      NS    B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.228.79.201
;
; FORMERLY C.PSI.NET
;
.                        3600000      NS    C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.33.4.12
;
; FORMERLY TERP.UMD.EDU
;
.                        3600000      NS    D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     199.7.91.13
D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.  3600000      AAAA  2001:500:2D::D
;
; FORMERLY NS.NASA.GOV
;
.                        3600000      NS    E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.203.230.10
;
; FORMERLY NS.ISC.ORG
;
.                        3600000      NS    F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.5.5.241
F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:2F::F
;
; FORMERLY NS.NIC.DDN.MIL
;
.                        3600000      NS    G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.112.36.4
;
; FORMERLY AOS.ARL.ARMY.MIL
;
.                        3600000      NS    H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     128.63.2.53
H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:1::803F:235
;
; FORMERLY NIC.NORDU.NET
;
.                        3600000      NS    I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.36.148.17
I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:7FE::53
;
; OPERATED BY VERISIGN, INC.
;
.                        3600000      NS    J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.58.128.30
J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:503:C27::2:30
;
; OPERATED BY RIPE NCC
;
.                        3600000      NS    K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     193.0.14.129
K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:7FD::1
;
; OPERATED BY ICANN
;
.                        3600000      NS    L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     199.7.83.42
L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:3::42
;
; OPERATED BY WIDE
;
.                        3600000      NS    M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     202.12.27.33
M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:DC3::35
; End of File
;end db.root
```

**zones.rfc1918:**

```
zone "10.in-addr.arpa"      { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "16.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "17.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "18.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "19.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "20.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "21.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "22.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "23.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "24.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "25.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "26.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "27.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "28.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "29.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "30.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "31.172.in-addr.arpa"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.empty"; };
// end zones.rfc1918
```